How to make Simplify run faster
So I have the function of an arbitrarily oriented torus and I wanted to run simplify on it to see if mathematica can find any simplifications on it. But Simplify and FullSimplify both run forever. I left it running for multiple days and it never terminated. So I was wondering what I can do before I run simplify to make simplify run faster here is the code below
P = {x, y, z}
torusA = {aX, aY, aZ}
torusB = {bX, bY, bZ}
Q = torusB - torusA
DirSignA = (Floor[Q[[1]]/(Abs[Q[[1]]] + 1)] - Floor[-Q[[1]]/(Abs[Q[[1]]] + 1)]) + 0.5
DirSignB = (Floor[Q[[2]]/(Abs[Q[[2]]] + 1)] - Floor[-Q[[2]]/(Abs[Q[[2]]] + 1)]) + 0.5
DirSignC = (Floor[Q[[3]]/(Abs[Q[[3]]] + 1)] - Floor[-Q[[3]]/(Abs[Q[[3]]] + 1)]) + 0.5
CopySignA = Floor[DirSignA/(Abs[DirSignA] + 1)] - Floor[-DirSignA/(Abs[DirSignA] + 1)]
CopySignB = Floor[DirSignB/(Abs[DirSignB] + 1)] - Floor[-DirSignB/(Abs[DirSignB] + 1)]
CopySignC = Floor[DirSignC/(Abs[DirSignC] + 1)] - Floor[-DirSignC/(Abs[DirSignC] + 1)]
w = {Q[[3]]*CopySignA, Q[[3]]*CopySignB, -((Abs[Q[[1]]] + Abs[Q[[2]]])*CopySignC)}
v = Cross[w, Q]
torusCenter = (torusB + torusA)/2
wNorm = (1/Sqrt[w . w]) w
vNorm = (1/Sqrt[v . v]) v
pointOffset = P - torusCenter
planarExtentA = pointOffset . vNorm
planarExtentB = pointOffset . wNorm
lval = (((pointOffset[[1]]^2) + (pointOffset[[2]]^2) + (pointOffset[[3]]^2) + R^2 - r^2)*((pointOffset[[1]]^2) + (pointOffset[[2]]^2) + (pointOffset[[3]]^2) + R^2 - r^2))
rval = 4 R^2 (planarExtentA^2 + planarExtentB^2)
FullSimplify[lval == rval]


Semicolons at the end of lines would suppress needless output. That would make it easier to work with your code.

Do it in steps.
lval = Simplify[lval]

This simplifies quickly.
Use a TimeConstraint.
rval = Simplify[rval, TimeConstraint -> 20]

You get considerable simplification for the first pass, or at least the output is much shorter.  You can repeat the command to possibly get more simplification, or maybe this is as simple as it gets.
